# Is there a difference between initialising express app via "app = new Express()" and "app = express()'

Tags: javascript, express

I've always seen express apps being initialised like:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
```

But today I stumbled upon a example with new operator:

```
var Express = require('express')
var app = new Express()
```

Is there any difference?

Source: https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/0d7c49318a8ed78bdef4022b9f0adc4bfb04bdba/src/server.js#L25

Comment: the second example is not correctly copied from the code you linked.  it uses `import Express from 'express';` not `var Express = require('express')`.  look up import vs require.

Comment: @Claies for others who happen on this, what difference is that?

Comment: I'm not an expert on script imports, but I know for sure they are entirely different.  `import` is from ES6.  I was merely trying to point out that your question is flawed because you posted the code incorrectly.

Comment: ES6 compilers (e.g. Babel) currently convert `import` statements into `require` calls.  There's not a significant difference unless using the `as` statement or destructuring.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a subtle difference, but one which doesn't make much (any?) difference in this case.

With `Node.js`'s `require` statement what you end up with is the object that the module assigns to `module.exports`.  This could be anything, even just a simple value, but it could also be a function.

Thus, suppose you have the following module in `myModule.js`:

```
function complexOperation() { 
   // blah blah 
   }
module.exports = complexOperation;
```

When you do:

`var myModule = require("myModule.js");`

You end up with `myModule` set to `complexOperation`, and you would call it just like any regular function.  Straightforward.  But note that it wouldn't necessarily make sense to do something like `new complexOperation()` here - all depends on what `complexOperation` is.

In the case of `Express.js` the object returned is itself a function, namely, `createApplication` (defined in this file: https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/express.js).  So `require('express')` returns a function, which is assigned to `express`, and which is then run on the next line.  So `app` ends up with the result of the execution of the function `createApplication`.

The second variation (ignoring the fact that, as one comment-er pointed out, you misquoted that source file) uses the `new` keyword.  When you do:

`var a = new Something();`

`Something` should be a function - a constructor function.  And what this statement does is:

- create a new object
- invokes `Something()` with `this` set to the new object
- returns the result of `Something()`

(There is more going on, with the object's prototypes being setup.  Full explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).

So in the above case, the statement `var app = new Express()` creates a new object, invokes `Express()` with `this` set up to refer to the newly created object, and then returns the result.

In the case of `Express.js`, because the thing exported is itself a function, much the same result is achieved.  A new object is created, `createApplication` is run with `this` setup accordingly, and then `app` gets the result of `createApplication`.